# Starting RoR/Best way to start

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Coming with a deep background in Backend Development using T-SQL, PL/SQL, SAP ABAP and some other old school languages like Visual FoxPro, Clarion, Cobol.

After some comparison (PHP, Python/Django, RoR, .NET), I decided to go with RoR. I'm not familiar with Web Development. I'm a typical Backend guy with very limited knowledge about Frontend (Web, HTML, CSS etc.etc.), but I have an idea and concept on how my frontend should look like.

How should I start learning? HTML/CSS first? Then RoR? Or, what is the best way to get up and running with Web/ROR development?

Answer (score 1):

First of learn ruby language from here

https://www.tutorialspoint.com/ruby/

Then start to learning Ruby on rails from this book

https://www.railstutorial.org/book

I think you don't need to learn HTML or CSS, you can learn that while learning Ruby on rails. 
If you want to get basic knowledge about HTML and CSS, you can check it out below
https://www.w3schools.com/html/
https://www.w3schools.com/css/

Hope this will answer your question